# Getting all services and their path to exe

Tags: c++, windows-services, exe

Get list of windows services and print name, status, path to exe

the above statement needs to be solved, I am aware we enum services to find.....since I am beginner ,I don't understand how to retrieve all the path to exe.

this is what I knew

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    SC_HANDLE sHandle;
    LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG lpServiceConfig = NULL;
    DWORD cbBufSize = 100;
    LPDWORD bytesNeeded = NULL;
    sHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL,NULL,SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    sHandle = OpenService(sHandle, "YOU SERVICE NAME",SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    QueryServiceConfig(sHandle,lpServiceConfig,cbBufSize,bytesNeeded);
    std::cout << lpServiceConfig->lpBinaryPathName << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What did the documentation pertaining to these functions have to say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`EnumServiceStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-enumservicesstatusa) to query which services are installed. You can then open each service to query its EXE path.

Also, your code is leaking resources and memory.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    DWORD bytesNeeded = 0;
    DWORD numServices = 0;
    DWORD resumeHandle = 0;

    SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
    if (!hSCManager) ...

    EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_STATE_ALL, NULL, 0, &bytesNeeded, &numServices, &resumeHandle);
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) ...

    std::vector<BYTE> enumBuffer(bytesNeeded);
    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS pEnum = reinterpret_cast<LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS>(enumBuffer.data());

    if (!EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_STATE_ALL, pEnum, bytesNeeded, &bytesNeeded, &numServices, &resumeHandle)) ...

    for(DWORD idx = 0; idx < numServices; ++idx)
    {
        std::cout << pEnum[idx].lpServiceName << " (" << pEnum[idx].lpDisplayName << ")" << std::endl;
        // use/display pEnum[idx].ServiceStatus as needed ...
   
        SC_HANDLE hService = OpenService(hSCManager, pEnum[idx].lpServiceName, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
        if (!hService) ...

        QueryServiceConfig(hSerivce, NULL, 0, &bytesNeeded);
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) ...

        std::vector<BYTE> configBuffer(bytesNeeded);
        LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG lpServiceConfig = reinterpret_cast<LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG>(configBuffer.data());

        if (!QueryServiceConfig(hSerivce, lpServiceConfig, bytesNeeded, &bytesNeeded)) ...

        std::cout << lpServiceConfig->lpBinaryPathName << std::endl;

        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    }

    CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
}
```